# How do I get Angular Isotope to be fully responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, responsive-design, jquery-isotope

I am trying to create a fully responsive version of Isotope using AngularJS/Angular-Isotope. I have created a non-AngularJS version that utilises this jQuery (found on Stackoverflow and other sources) to make the columns and items responsive:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var $container = $('#one-column'),
   margin = 10,
   colWidth = function () {
    var w = $container.width(), 
            columnNum = 1,
            columnWidth = 0;
        if (w > 1200) {
            columnNum  = 5;
        } else if (w > 1024) {
            columnNum  = 4;
        } else if (w > 768) {
            columnNum  = 3;
        } else if (w > 480) {
            columnNum  = 2;
        }
    columnWidth = Math.floor(w/columnNum);
    var $item = $('.story'),
            width = columnWidth-10
            $item.css({ width: width });
        var $featured = $('.featured'),         
            dblwidth = columnWidth*2-10
            if (w > 480) {
                $featured.css({
                    width: dblwidth
                });
            } else {
                $featured.css({
                    width: width
                });
            }
    return columnWidth;
   };
   $(window).on('throttledresize', isotope);
});
```

Introducing Angular to this jQuery version causes the masonry layout to sporadically load or not load - with no errors, so I have used [ManKindSoftware's Angular Isotope](https://github.com/mankindsoftware/angular-isotope) to load items and then filter accordingly - which loads every time. However on initial load the items are all a fixed height and the columns are adaptive rather than responsive. I cannot seem to figure out how I can flexibly change the column widths based on resizing and make the columns and isotope items responsive.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Comment: why you don;t try `$(window).on('resize', isotope);`

Comment: Unfortunately that only works with the regular version of isotope not angular isotope.

Comment: why you don't wrote jquery code in directive?

Comment: Yes this is something I have just thought I should try, I am new to Angular so just getting my head round it. Thank you.